# "m is not defined" discord.js messagecollector

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord collector like this:

```
let user = message.author;
let guest = message.mentions.users.first()

const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, m => m.author.id === message.author.id || m.author.id === guest.id, {
  time: 60000,
  max: 100,
  maxMatches: 100
});

collector.on('collect', message => {
  if (message.content == "a" && m.author.id === message.author.id) {
    message.channel.send("b")
  } else if (message.content == "a" && m.author.id === guest.id) {
    message.channel.send("c")
  }
})
```

When **USER** write this command (`prefix + command + @guest`) and then says "a", the bot will reply with "b", and if **GUEST** says "a", the bot will reply with "c".

The problem is that `m` is not defined, how can I fix this?

Comment: Where do you expect `m` to be coming from? I see you have it in the callback function parameter of the `MessageCollector` construction, but I don't see that `m` is defined anywhere in the scope of your `collector.on` function.

Comment: how can i define it? m = ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this:

```
collector.on('collect', message => {...});
```

To this:

```
collector.on('collect', m => {...});
```

Then `message` is the original message and `m` is the collected message.